# Property not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I've a problem with a `datagrid` on a simple windows form project (framework 4.0, VS2010). 
In the code behind is not possible to access to the `datagrid.Columns` property. Am I missing an assembly reference?

These are my references:

```
Microsoft.CSharp,
System,
System.Core,
System.Data,
System.Data.DataSetExtensions,
System.Data.Entity,
System.Deployment,
System.Drawing,
System.Runtime.Serialization,
System.Security,
System.Windows.Forms,
System.Windows.Form.Ribbon35,
System.xml,
System.Xml.Linq,
WindowsBase,
WPFToolkit.Extended
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't see the System.Windows.Controls and you need that.

Assembly for datagrid columns: system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns

Also I want to suggest you [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) a very nice tools when you have missing assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Camilo,
but the thing is that I can't find System.Windows.Control reference in .net tab (Add Reference from VS) and also Resharper doesn't help me (I dont' have any suggestions if I write dtgXXX.Columns) because the datagrid is visible (so I can refer to it with dtgXXX.) but the property Columns is missing.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using datagrid or datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I figured out. That property seems to exist for wpf components only. In fact, for Windows form the datagrid assembly is System.Windows.Form while for wpf component is PrsentationFramework (System.Windows.Controls)